# Count of files between 2 size in Linux

Tags: linux, find

Hi I want to find count of file between 2 size (for example 1k and 2k) in linux, I found that the code return the count of exact size in a directory and it work fine:

```
find DIR_NAME -type f | wc -l
```

could anyone help me how I do find between 2 size? And is it possible that I find the count of `Hiden` file via `find` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two `size` flags together for this and use `+`, `-` for greater than and less than size.

`find DIR_NAME -type f -size +1k -size -2k | wc -l`

Comment: Are you sure `-size +1k -size -2k` is doing what you think it is?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to specify the minimum and maximum size in `k`. For example for files between `1k` and `2k` in size you can write:

```
$ find . -type f -size +1k ! -size +2k | wc -l
```

That is size of at least `1k` but NOT size greater than `2k`.

**note:** the size is in `k` (e.g. `1024` bytes)

To your point in the comments, to find `hidden` files, you can either user a *regex*, e.g. `find . -type f -regex '^[.][/][.].*$'` or just use a *glob* for `-name`, e.g. `find . -type f -name "\.*"`

Comment: thanks..do you know how i find number of hidden file?

Comment: Use `-regex`, e.g. `find . -type f -regex '^[.].*$'`

Comment: I use this code but the result of `regex '^[.].*$'` is same as without use that, could you please help me?

Comment: Better use `'^[.][/][.].*$'`.